# UPDATE varias filas de sqlite en python

Tags: python, sqlite, update

Tengo una duda sobre actualizar datos de una BD.

Tengo 2 tablas.
Una es la principal (productos)
La otra es de uso temporal(temporalcompras), para agregar y/o quitar cantidades de stock.
Entonces, saco de 'temporalcompras' el stock que ingreso,
ej: stock=[10, 10, 25]

```
    conexion=self.conectar()
    cursor=conexion.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT stock FROM temporalcompra')
    stock=[]
    for i in cursor.fetchall():
        stock.append(i[0])
    print(stock)
```

y los productos a los cuales los tengo que actualizar.

Ej: productos=['ABROCHADORA PINZA SABONIS G 880', 'ACRILICO DECORATIVO 50 CC MET ORO RICO', 'RESALTADOR COLLEGE PTA.BISELADA NARANJA - HY1002-CS']

```
cursor.execute('SELECT producto FROM temporalcompra')
    producto=[]
    for i in cursor.fetchall():
        producto.append(i[0])
    print(producto)
```

con esos productos, busco el stock que hay actualmente en la tabla principal:
ej: lista=[1, 5, 1]

```
    lista=[]
    for i in producto:
        cursor.execute('SELECT stock FROM productos WHERE producto=(?)', [i])
        for e in cursor.fetchall() :
            lista.append(e[0])

    print(lista)
```

Realizo la suma entre el principal y en nuevo,

```
    actualizacion = []

    for i in range(len(stock)):
        actualizacion.append(stock[i])
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        actualizacion[i] = actualizacion[i] + lista[i]
```

para luego volver a modificarlos en el principal

ej: actualizacion=[11, 15, 26]

Esta es la suma de stock+lista y es la que necesito actualizar a la BD

```
        cursor.execute('''UPDATE productos 
        SET stock = CASE producto 
        WHEN (?) THEN (?) 
        END 
        WHERE producto IN (?)''', (str(producto),str(actualizacion),str(producto)))
    conexion.commit()
```

Es el único método que encontré posible para realizar esto, pero no se si es el correcto.
No me salta ningún tipo de error, pero tampoco me genera el cambio.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: No entiendo para que hacer un case dentro del set (que tengo mis dudas de si anda en sqlite... ).. porque no verificas afuera lo del case? igual tu consulta tampoco tiene mucho sentido, porque el case es igual que el where por lo tanto se va a actualizar el stock.. o deberia.. ahora.. producto es una lista, y no podes pasar de parametro una lista.. actualizacion es una lista y tampoco podes pasarla de parametro... update funciona de a un registro por ves, no con lista de datos...

Comment: Si update, es de uno a la vez, que puedo utilizar, si como en este caso, quiero actualizar mas de una fila de la misma columna? Ahora actualizo la pregunta para ver si se aclara un poco mas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dándole vueltas al coco, se me ocurrió transformar las listas de "actualización" y "productos" en un diccionario. Y luego aplicarle un `for`, modificando este código

```
 cursor.execute('''UPDATE productos 
    SET stock = CASE producto 
    WHEN (?) THEN (?) 
    END 
    WHERE producto IN (?)''', (str(producto),str(actualizacion),str(producto)))
conexion.commit()
```

por este otro:

```
union=dict(zip(producto,actualizacion))
elementos = union.items()
for i,e in elementos:
    cursor.execute('''UPDATE productos 
        SET stock=?
        WHERE producto=(?)''', (str(e),str(i)))
    conexion.commit()
```

Esto modifica la base de datos correctamente por ahora.
Espero que sea una respuesta correcta.